# Algorithm for Ratio on Java

Tags: java, math, logic

Let's say I have a huge list of words and an array that is filled with a random variety of combinations of those words. A slot may hold either one or more words, with no limit on the amount of words in that particular and words may repeat. (When I say slot, I mean the string full of words marked for separation in the array)

Imagine a web of all possible words wherein their proximity to each other is determined by the frequency by which they have appeared together in slots.

e.g. If word1 and word2 have appeared together more frequently than words3 and word2 have, their "proximity" variable should be smaller than the variable between between word3 and word2. I need the **ratio**

How would I determine an algorithm can calculate a ratio of "proximity" between all possible words in the web?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dependent frequency:

```
f = f(w1 and w2) / f(w1 or w2)
```

where `f(w1 and w2)` is the number of slots where both words appear and `f(w1 or w2)` is the number of slots where at least one of both words appears. If both words only appear together, you get `f = 1`. If both words never appear together, you get `f = 0`.

You can easily map this to a distance-like value via `distance = k * (1 - f)` for some scaling factor `k`.